# Jquery Rule validation for allowing integer and space

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My current validator for accepting integer is

```
$( "#UserForm" ).validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
      minlength: 6,
    }
  }
});
```

It works fine

But now i want to make change in it so as to accept spaces also.

What should be my code?Please help i'm beginner in jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `pattern` rule defined in the additional-method.js file

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#UserForm").validate({
    rules: {
      contact: {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[\d\s]+$/,
        minlength: 6,
      }
    },
    messages: {
      contact: {
        pattern: 'Please enter digits or space characters only'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="UserForm" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <input name="contact" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```